# Unable to launch Mongo Db Shell

Tags: mongodb

I have downloaded mongoDb binary distribution from URL "http://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl" and extracted it in my C drive ( Windows 7). But I am unable to access mongo shell using the mongo command. I downloaded node.js binary version and used the same method and it ran successfully. I want to ask if there is a way to run mongo db using the binary distribution. I don't have admin privileges. Any help in this regard is welcome.

Comment: can you provide error log?

Comment: @Harsh Patel, Hi harsh, Actually I am not getting any error. the command prompt just consumes the "mongo" command and does nothing

Comment: run `mongo -help`, it gives any output ?

Comment: Did you get the zip or the msi installer? When you just unpack the zip, the command line tools don't get added to the `PATH` environment variable. Either do that or navigate to the bin folder before you try to launch the commands. This is more of a basic windows user question.

Comment: @philipp I am in bin folder itself, so no need to set path and i am not getting any error like "'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,".  I have got the zip folder, unpacked it and just trying to run the mongo.

Comment: @HarshPatel mongo --help is not giving any output.

Comment: can you see `mongod.exe` in processes tab of Windows Task Manager

Comment: @HarshPatel     no, I am not able to see any mongod.exe in process tab of windows.

Comment: Please start `mongod` server using `mongod --dbpath` command, also try `mongod -help`

Comment: @HarshPatel Hi, I am not able to start mongod server using the mongod --dbpath command.

Comment: can you provide error?

Comment: @HarshPatel harsh it is not giving me any error. It just consumes my command and produces nothing, not even error.